# Can we specify a domain when redirect user to sign in with oauth2 in appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth

When we were using the UserService api, we can specify a domain when generate auth url. But when we switch to oauth2 (with google client library for java API), we are using AuthorizationCodeFlow.newAuthorizationUrl() to generate auth url, however we cannot specify any domain, so for example, if one customer already logged in with his gmail account in some other google sites, but he want to sign in our app with another google apps account, he has to  logout from google site since the authFlow always get the gmail account credential, we don't have a way to force him log in to a specific domain. We didn't have this issue when using UserService api.

Just want to know if there is any solution for this.

Comment: from the docs : Google Apps domains and appspot.com domains, including version-specific appspot.com domains, are supported. Note that authorization is associated with the domain used to access the endpoints: an access token produced using endpoints on one domain cannot be used to access the app using a different domain. If the access token came from a version-specific appspot.com domain, it can only be used to access that version of the app, and only at that domain.

Comment: Understand that the credential for one domain cannot be used in another. My problem is that we want to help customer to choose a proper account when sign in with oauth2. You know sometimes if user click the wrong account, or if he only logged in with gmail account but want to sign in with google apps account, he has to log out from google sites and login our app again which is not so convenience. We were using the appengine UserService API to generate auth url, and at that time we can speicify a domain so he will log in to the proper domain. I just want to check if we can do the same in oauth2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attach "hd=$domain" to the OAuth2 authorization request query parameters it will prompt user to login to that domain (if user not yet logged in) and/or optimize selection of the user's account in that domain.

Comment: Many thanks, it solved my problem. I found the oauth2 url parameters on google doc based on your answer, I didn't noticed that becaused I was using google client library for java and the "hd" parameter was not wrapped as "setXXX" method in AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl class. But now I can use AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl.put(field, value) method to set "hd" to restrict user login to specific domain now. Thanks again.